# Read File, jump lines and store data in array.

Tags: c++, arrays, file, text-parsing

I am kind of new to C++ and I have a problem with my program. I have looked for hours and days and even though there are a lot of posts similar to this one, I can't figure out why my program doesn't work.

I have a file that contains data in this way.

STRING FLOAT FLOAT

STRING INT

STRING FLOAT FLOAT FLOAT

STRING INT INT

FLOAT

FLOAT
...

So the first few lines have string for the first column and number for the rest, and at some point there are just float number.

I have managed to get the data up to where all the floats start but I can't figure out how to store the rest of number in an array. (I KNOW IT WOULD BE A LOT EASIER TO DO IT WITH VECTOR BUT I HAVE TO DO IT WITH ARRAYS).

This is what I have done.

```
void getData(string *ext, int size)
{
   istringstream is(*ext);
   float val;
   is >> val;
   float *arrVal = new float[10];    // I dont know the size of the Array.

   if(typeid(val) == typeid(float))  //IM NOT SURE ABOUT THIS AT ALL. I JUST DON'T KNOW HOW TO GET TO THE LINE WHERE THERE ARE NO STRINGS
   {
      arr[size] = atof(*ext.c_str());
    }                                  // I think this part is why it does not work.

int main()
{
ifstream File("t.txt");         
string line;                                        
int nLines(0);                                  
float *arrayValues =  new float[12];                


if(!inFile)                                         
{
    cerr << "Cannot open file." << endl;
    return -1;
}
else
{       
    while(getline(File, line))
    {
        getValues(&line, nLines);
        getPoints(&line);   //this function gets the values of the first lines.

        ++nLines;

    }
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

So basically I have to figure out how to jump to the line where all the floats start and how to store those in an array. 
I am sure there is a bunch of errors. I hope you guys get what I am trying to do. I really have looked everywhere and can't find anything.

Thank you !!

Comment: What do getPoints(&line) and getValues(&line, nLines) do?

Comment: You're right about the errors. This doesn't compile. Kindly post something that does. And do you know what a *reference* is?

Comment: Oh, getPoints should be the getData above, I just changed it the name. The getvalues gets the first lines, the ones that start with the string.

Comment: You have several problems strung together: 1) parsing the file and finding the place where the floats start, 2) reading them in, and 3) storing them in an array. It's best to tackle -- and ask for help with -- one problem a time.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need to do. So to parse the file I use getLine right? I just don't know how to jump the lines...I have looked everywhere and I can't figure it out.

Comment: You're already "jumping" lines as you read them with `getline()`. Each  line should be checked for starting with a valid `float`. If there is none, then continue to the next line. If there is, keep that value as the "first" and enter a different loop that streams in the remaining floats and accumulates them (along with the first) into an array that is resized as needed.

Answer (score 0):

As you read each file, you get data in a char. So,
- Tokenize each line read by spaces using strtok. This logic doesnt work, if your string has spaces in between. It works fine, if your string is only one word like "STRRING" or "FLOAT". It doesnt work if your string is like "I am a Genius" :)
- Validate each token a simple if condition should do your job. strings start with [a-z] or [A-Z]. Numbers use [0-9].
-Once valiadated. perform the required conversions using atoi or itoa, or others.

Comment: When you say each file, do you mean each line of the file? So you are talking about the main function or the getData?

Comment: Yes, i meant each line of the file, which is being read. :) Thanks for pointing it out. shall take care from now on.

Answer (score 0):

This skeleton will skip any line in the file that isn't a floating point number.

```
bool isFloat(string s)
{
    bool result = true;
    bool decimalSeen = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        if(s[i] == '.')
        {
            if(!decimalSeen)
            {
                decimalSeen = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }

    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream File("t.txt");         
    string line;

    if(!File.is_open())                                         
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open file." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {       
        while(getline(File, line))
        {
            if(isFloat(line))
            {
                float val = atof(line.c_str());
                // Now add to array
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to use an array you will have to make a new bigger one and copy over the values. General idea:

```
int maxSize = 10;
float* a = new float[maxSize];
// use a until it is full then
float* b = new float[maxSize*2];
memcpy(b, a, sizeof(float)*maxSize);
maxSize *= 2;
float* temp = a;
// make a point to new array
a = b;
// free memory a was using before
delete[] temp;
```